# Marker Support Extension Point enabled only for a concrete Perspective

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, markers, perspective

We have developed our own perspective, and we want to limit all shown markers so they fit our own Project Explorer content provider, which contains a subset of all project files and folders.
We have already added an org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerSupport to plugin extension points, but we found this markers content configuration applies to all perspectives.

Is there a way to enable this configuration only for our perspective? 
As a first aproximation, we have added our content provider to PerspectiveListeners, so we will be able to do something (already don't know what) when our perspective changes or activates. This may not be the correct or simplest way to start, so any help would be very apreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The markers are not tied with perspectives. So all the markers will be available in all the perspectives. There are no plans to do that, so you are on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Prakash. If markers are not tied to perspectives, is there a way to set and unset programmatically a given Content Configuration? As you would do in "Problems" tab, then "Configure Contents" properties, and then radio buttons within Configurations list area... This way we could simulate this tie behaviour from markers to perspective, listening to Perspective changes and setting marker configurations programmatically. Please help!

Comment: There is no API. Look at the org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.FiltersConfigurationDialog for how it uses the internal classes to manipulate the configurations. I've redone the UI for 3.7 along with changes in few internal classes, so make sure you get the latest Milestone/I-build to experiment